# Can't Upload File On Buddy.com's Parse

Tags: parse-platform, buddy.com

I started using Parse-on-Buddy on the Buddy.com website recently.  In the last couple of days, I am having issues trying to upload any kind of file to any of my classes using the web-browser.  If I post a new object from the app I have built for it, the file uploads, but won't from the web.  I have tried Safari and Chrome on my MacBook, both with the same results.  I've reached out to support but without anyone getting in touch with me, and never answering their phone.  Anyone else come across this issue and know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with dashboard file uploads and app keys, where if any app keys have been created, additionally there needs to be a JavaScript app key created for uploads to succeed. Create one by logging in to the Parse on Buddy dashboard at https://parse.buddy.com, navigating to your app, then going to 'App Settings' -> 'Security & Keys'. Click on the 'Create' button next to the 'JavaScript key' section. Thanks.